# ENVIAR ARCHIVO A WebService RestApi con Método POST en C#

Tags: c#, post

Con el siguiente método, de una aplicación de escritorio C#:

```
    public string GetPost (string url)
    {
        string respuesta = "";
        WebRequest oRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);


        oRequest.Method = "post";
        oRequest.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";

        using (var oSW = new StreamWriter(oRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"alumno\":\"pedro\",\"edad\":\"15\"}";

            oSW.Write(json);
            oSW.Flush();
            oSW.Close();
        }

        WebResponse oResponse = oRequest.GetResponse();

        using (var oSR = new StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            respuesta = oSR.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        }

        return respuesta;
    }
```

Yo envío un string Json a un WebService RestApi y me retorna un json de respuesta.

Pero ahora lo que necesito es enviar un archivo comprimido a ese webservice, en lugar de un string json.  Y además debo autenticarme con un usuario y password en el webservice.  Pero no logro encontrar la forma correcta de hacerlo.  Algo que si he podido averiguar es que en ContentType debo poner form-data, pero no sé que más hacer?  Alguien puede ayudarme.

Comment: Siempre uso la clase httpclient para enviar y recibir info. Se que seteas el header  con "zip-deflat"

Comment: Gracias Ramiro.  investigaré esa clase a ver como me va.

Comment: ya te paso yo un ejemplo para enviar un post con esa clase

Answer (score 0):

Te agrego un ejemplo de las formas de usar el gzip.

```
    HttpClient client;

    public async Task<bool> Post(Uri uri, object entidad = default)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entidad);
        httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();
        var cont = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

        httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(uri.ToString(), cont);

        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Hola Ramiro.  Con ese código que enviaste se supone que puedo enviar cualquier archivo .gz a un webservice???  El asunto es que para yo poder subir el archivo al webservice necesito especificar también un usuario y una contraseña.  En ese código tuyo en que parte se especifica la ruta del archivo comprimido que yo quiero enviar?  Disculpa por tanta preguntadera.